# ORACLE : Update multiple columns error : Can not update string to NULL

Tags: oracle, sql-update, runtime-error, multiple-columns

I have a simple update stament as:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 SET (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c) = 
 (SELECT t2.x, t2.y, t3.z 
  FROM table_2 t2, table_3 t3, table_4 t4
  WHERE 
  1 = 1
  AND t2.id = t3.id
  AND t2.id1 = t4.id1
  AND t2.name = t1.name
  ) WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM t2
 WHERE
 1 = 1
 AND t2.name = t1.name
)
```

Inner SELECT query gives me results. But when I execute whole UPDATE query, it fails with error:
ORA-01407 "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
It also  says that update on t1.a to NULL not possible. Please let me know, if I have made any mistake in this update query.

Please note that I can not use MERGE statement because there is a possibility that t2.name = t1.name condition may give me more than one entry from table t2. And in this case merge statement may fail with error can not get stable set of rows. If there is any other better appraoch let me know.

Update: t1.a has NOT NULL constraints. And my inner query returns results which do not have t2.x as NULL.

Comment: Your column most likely has a not null constraint...

Comment: this where 1=1 makes me sick

Comment: Sorry MUG4N, this is just for testing. I do not keep it in my final code. @Ben: I updated my query.

Comment: MUG4N, WHERE 1=1 is useful when debugging as it allows you to comment in/out all of your restrictions to observe the different results. If you comment out the WHERE keyword, you have to rewrite the first condition from AND to WHERE, which is annoying and takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be that your SQL in SET part is more selective than SQL in EXITS. If so, change your exists to 
     `... EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from 

     FROM table_2 t2, table_3 t3, table_4 t4 

     WHERE 

     t2.id = t3.id 

     AND t2.id1 = t4.id1 

     AND t2.name = t1.name`

---

Also all your x,y, or z columns should have not null value if you a,b,c are defined as not null (all x should be not null if t1.a is not null etc)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why I was getting that error. With condition t2.name = t1.name I was getting two rows in table table_1. For first row I had value t2.x from inner select query. For second row I did not. Thus I was getting the error. I modified my query as below:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 SET (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c) = 
 (SELECT t2.x, t2.y, t3.z 
  FROM table_2 t2, table_3 t3, table_4 t4
  WHERE 
  1 = 1
  AND t2.id = t3.id
  AND t2.id1 = t4.id1
  AND t2.name = t1.name
  ) WHERE t1.id, t1.name IN
(SELECT t1.id, t1.name FROM table_2 t2, table_3 t3, table_4 t4
  WHERE 
  1 = 1
  AND t2.id = t3.id
  AND t2.id1 = t4.id1
  AND t2.name = t1.name
)
```

Hope it will help others.